# Installing Multiple Instances Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-module-jpa, mule-cluster

I have gone through the mule doc.
https://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2INTRO/Installing+Mule
I am trying to understand how to make multiple instances from a single esb server.
I have to make a cluster of the instance.
But I havent get any clear idea about doing this.

I am using a ubuntu OS.

I want to know that.
1) Do I have to make 2 directory which containing to 2 server.
2 if no Do I have to configure 1 server So that I can make as many instance as I can.
3 if yes Then please can some one help me with step.

Answer (score 1):

I often set up multiple mule instances on Ubuntu linux in parallel, and I use parallel directories that contain the Mule standalone installation.

Here is a template upstart script I have used to run it on startup under the mule user.  You should copy this file to /etc/init/mule-*instance-name*.conf, and create an associated file /etc/default/mule-*instance-name* in which you set the MULE_HOME environment variable to the directory where you installed that instance.

```
description "Run Mule ESB instance 1"
author "Ryan Hoegg"
setuid mule
setgid nogroup 

# we need real ethernet before starting:
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel [016]
kill timeout 30
script
    . /etc/default/mule-instance1
    exec $MULE_HOME/bin/mule
end script
```

Comment: Hey @Ryan thanks for the reply.But it make me more confused.
I found one link in mule doc and They have given very good example 
https://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULEINTRO/Running+Mule
You can check with this link.

Comment: Hello @ManojSingh.  I don't use that method as the behavior is not what I want on different versions of linux.  Instead, I simply extract Mule Standalone into multiple directories (under /opt or /usr/local depending on sysadmin preference) and create multiple parallel startup scripts as above.

Comment: I have also did the same thing as you mention.I have also copy the server in 2 directories and start the 2 server in different port e.g 34565 and 56784 .After that I added that 2 server in a cluster.I want to know.Did I have done write??

Comment: Yes, if you were able to create the cluster in MMC you did do it correctly.

Comment: Hey @Ryan I want 1 help from your side I want one html page to display at first and then It take some value and give to http inbound point.So will you explain me hot to call first page in mule.I dont want the page of other web application.I just want my page in mule only.
Thanks for the help

Comment: You can do that in your flow by using a choice router and branching based on the path you received from the client.  Perhaps this question would be better answered in a new Question rather than a comment though.